# Generics Handling LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>

Tags: java, generics, collections, snakeyaml

I have never been that good in Generics but I used SnakeYaml.
Is there a way to let me fix this code

```
public class MyService{
private static Map<String, LinkedHashMap> myYamlMap;

public static void filter(Map<String, String>){
    //myYaml map reads the YAML File using SnakeYaml
    //Snake Yaml returns data in this format <String,LinkedHashMap>
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(); 
    Object object = yaml.load(reader); 
    Map<String, LinkedHashMap> myYamlMap = (Map<String, LinkedHashMap>)object; 

    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap> mainMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>)myYamlMap.get("sample");
}
```

}
and get away with this compile time warnings?

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:MyService [line: 69] - filter(Map<String, String>)
    - Type safety: Unchecked cast from LinkedHashMap to LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedHashMap>
    - LinkedHashMap is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedHashMap<K,V> should be 
     parameterized
    - LinkedHashMap is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedHashMap<K,V> should be 
     parameterized
```

Snakeyaml..uses LinkedHashMap in its construct and I wanted to get away with the casting.

Comment: Why not make the value have the type parameters `Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>>`

Comment: Tried that same issue.

Comment: okay. The last LinkedHashMap must also be typed

Comment: Can you share your code mate? So that I could look

Comment: My code?. I don't have any code. What I meant is that all references to `LinkedHashMap` must have appropriate type arguments.

Comment: You should post the actual code which produces these warnings. I don't see the usage of `filter` anywhere in your post, for instance.

Comment: @lexicore I placed it now mate.. I thought it was clear.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given your code:

```
private static Map<String, LinkedHashMap> myYamlMap;
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap> mainMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>)myYamlMap.get("sample");
```

This doesn't make sense.

```
private static Map<String, LinkedHashMap> myYamlMap;
```

This should probably be

```
private static Map<String, Map<Key, Value>;
myYamlMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<Key, Value>>;
myYamlMap.put("key1", new LinkedHashMap<Key,Value>();
```

for some `Key` and `Value` types, which aren't specified in your code...
OR something more complex -- see below

```
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap> mainMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>)myYamlMap.get("sample");
```

Your use of `get` here seems to imply that `myYamlMap` should be

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, Map<Key, Value>> myYamlMap;
myYamlMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Map<Key,Value>>>;
Map<Key,Value> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Key,Value>();
temp.put(k1, value1);
myYamlMap.put("sample", temp);
```

since you seem to be expecting `get()` to return a `Map<String,Map<Key,Value>>` from within the outer collection.

NOW you can do

```
Map<String, Map<Key,Value>> mainMap = myYamlMap.get("sample");
```

The reason for using the `Map` interface is that nowhere in your code do you use methods specific to `LinkedHashMap` so declarations should all be using just `Map<...>` except when instantiating the maps.

Comment: I have edited my code to show the values.  Can you check again.  I have removed most of the clutter.